# What's wrong with this Batch file?

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to write a simple Batch file.

"encoded_%%A_%%B_%int%*%conv%*%%E" is a required output file name. Can someone tell me, why "int" and "conv" never appear in the name? It treats them like they don't exist... why?

```
FOR %%A IN (4k, 8k) DO FOR %%B IN (7, 8) DO FOR %%C IN (1/32, 1/4) DO FOR %%D IN (2/3, 5/6) DO FOR %%E IN (4, 64) DO (
if %%C==1/32 (set int=132) else (set int=14)
if %%D==2/3 (set conv=23) else (set conv=56)
dvbtenco -i zad1.m2v -o encoded_%%A_%%B_%int%_%conv%_%%E -m %%A -M %%E -p %%D -D %%C -b %%B -d t
timeout /t 10

)
```

Comment: you need delayed expansion - http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: not directly an answer to the question, but: do you know that almost all Windows versions support windows scripting host ? Wsh allows you to use javascript and can be used together with batch files. It can be a replacement or you can call wsh from a batch.

Comment: @npocmaka - Delayed expansion helped, thanks.

Comment: @Marged - I didn't know that. Thanks for such a hint, I will read about that. :)

Comment: May I suggest that npocmaka post his comment as answer and Kacper accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npocmaka has the obvious solution in his comment - Use delayed expansion.

But there is a less obvious solution that avoids delayed expansion. All it requires is two more FOR loops.

The `/` is typically (but not always) synonymous with `\` when dealing with paths, so `1/32\..` is logically equivalent to `1`. You can use the `~n` modifier to get the normalized name contained within a FOR variable, without the path.

```
FOR %%A IN (4k, 8k) DO FOR %%B IN (7, 8) DO FOR %%C IN (1/32, 1/4) DO FOR %%D IN (2/3, 5/6) DO FOR %%E IN (4, 64) DO (
  for %%c in (%%C\..) do for %%d in (%%D\..) do (
    dvbtenco -i zad1.m2v -o encoded_%%A_%%B_%%~nc%%~nC_%%~nd%%~nD_%%E -m %%A -M %%E -p %%D -D %%C -b %%B -d t
  )
  timeout /t 10
)
```